# How to display specific line from a text by knowing its beginning?

Tags: bash, text, awk, sed, grep

I have a huge text file (30 GB) I want to display a specific line from this file which I know starts with "813B246B". How can I do this using bash?

Comment: Do you know how to use grep?

Comment: @HerbWolfe No, but if you give the command it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bash command

```
grep "^813B246B"  YourFileName
```

Comment: can I run this on bash?

Comment: No.  This is perl.  If you want  to use a bash command,  do what @Herb Wolfe said.  Use grep.